# why the equals method of object class is called instead of Arrays class while working with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
int[] arr={1,2,3};
int[] arr1={1,2,3};
System.out.print(arr.equals(arr1));//false
```

When I use arr.equals(arr1) .equals() of Object.class is called instead of Arrays.class why????
if .equals() of Arrays.class is called it could have checked the content,since they are equal.It returns  true.

Comment: `arr` isn't an instance of the `Arrays` class.  It's an instance of `int[]`.

Comment: and `int[]` or any other array type (unfortunately) do not override `equals()`